# How do I highlight a certain city on world Map using jVectorMap plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, world-map, jvectormap

I need to have a small identifier to highlight the particular city on Map using jVectorMap. what would be the Ideal way to do so. May be I can put something like image(say 3px wide and high red coloured near San Francisco) on Map. This way users can locate the precise location rather than USA in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the last version of [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/examples/markers-world/).

Comment: Thanks Buddy, Thats Awesome, what is new coming in jvectormap. Can we customize those yellow dots and put some decent markers.Can I help.

Comment: I'm finishing new fully rewritten version of jVectorMap. For now you can change color and size of the marker. I'm going to add markers defined as images later.

Answer (score 1):

jVectorMap does just that, draw vectors. I don't see any mention in the API of defining true "points". So you can either draw a tiny polygon around San Fransisco, or you can overlay your own image manually. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hRft/1/)

```
<img src="http://www.changosurf.com/images/marker_red.png" id="sanFranMarker" title="San Fransisco"/>
```

...

```
#map-usa {    position: relative;    width: 600px;    height: 400px;}
#sanFranMarker{    position: absolute;    top: 160px;    left:17px;}
```

Comment: Thanks a Ton Buddy, But I need to put this dark red color on World Map rather than USA Map.
Ok And ya, how do I locate the precise point on World Map, Coz vast the map, the more challenging it will become to locate the exact point, If I have to select two neighbouring cities

Comment: Ans I see one limitation to this implementation, that if you hover exactly over the image, It over rides the default jvectormap behavior of highlighting the State

Comment: Is there any solution to the second limitation

Comment: sorry mate, anything you do is going to be a hack in some way. "points" just don't mean anything in that plugin. If it's a problem to lose the hover effect on California when hovering on the over-laid image then there are other ways of making it look like that red dot is there, but you'll have to ask yourself what to do about the competing tooltips?
Bottom line: if you want a map, go to the experts. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

Comment: can you provide a link? the map on the fiddle I provided has an absolute size, so no it won't change on resize. If you've made a fluid map then it will take javascript to move it back into position on browser resize.

Comment: I cant upload a screen grab here, Anyways If I draw a tiny polygon around San Francisco, will it have the same limitations as having an image is there, Also do I need Raphael to draw a polygon or is there any other smart way. Thanks